# How should I use hooks in a nested component

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I'm building an app with React Native, and I have a card component.
This card component needs few hooks, the problem is that the card components being rendered in FlatList in a HomeScreen component.

So the hierarchy is like this:

```
-Homescreen Component
---FlatList
----Card1
----Card2
----Card3
```

From what I understand, it is not possible to use React Hooks in my card component (Invalid hook call error). which means I can't use something like PanGestureHandler because I need to use hooks for that.
I couldn't find anything, but I'm sure this is a common problem and there is a solution for this.
What is the best way to deal with this?

This is my FlatList:

```
  <FlatList
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    style={{padding: 8}}
    data={goals}
    renderItem={({index}) => GoalCard(goals[index], theme, hook1, hook2)}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
  />
```

This is my card:

```
const GoalCard = (goal: IGoal, theme: any, hook1: any, hook2: any) => {   ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested  hooks even inside flatlist make sure your Component name start with Capital latter  and if possible share more info about error

after changing this use props.hook1 etc.

```
<FlatList
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    style={{padding: 8}}
    data={goals}
    renderItem={({index}) => <GoalCard index={goals[index]} theme={theme} hook1={hook1} hook2={hook2})}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
  />
```

Comment: Is it possible to get an example please? I tried having the hooks in HomeScreen component, and then passing them as props to GoalCard but it also didn't work. Is this what you meant?

Comment: is it possible to you to share code of flatlist and your component how you exactly passing as props

Comment: Sure! I added it to the original post. Hope that is clear enough. I didn't add the whole components because there would be too much text.

Comment: check i have updated ans may this will work

Comment: Thanks! I tried this now, but it is not possible, it is trying to set hook1 again and there is an error (as hook1 is const)

Comment: can share code of GoalCard and how you declare state and how you set new value

Comment: Haven't got there yet. I just tried to set up the pan gesture stuff (following a tutorial) and got this error.

Comment: that's great  i hope you got this

Comment: Thank you very much! My bad, I completely got confused and used the solution wrong, tried again and it is working!

Answer (score 1):

you can pass hook down as prop, see the example.

```js
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(1);

<FlatList renderItem={({item}) => <Card value={value} setValue={setValue}/>


const Card = ({value, setValue}) => {
    return <Text onPress={() => setValue(value + 1)}>click me</Text>
}
```